# Installing libxml-dev package

Tags: package-management

I need this package installed http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxml-dev

But can't find it Ubuntu software center. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure don't you want `libxml++1.0-dev` or `libxml2-dev`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`libxml-dev` was last [seen in Hardy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+package/libxml-dev) - so if you definitely still need this package, you could try downloading the deb appropriate to your platform and installing this.

`libxml2-dev` is available from software center or synaptic.